# Docker env variables not set while log via shell

Tags: django, ubuntu, docker

In my settings file i am getting env variables like this

```
'NAME': os.environ['PG_DBNAME'],  # Database
```

I am setting in docker file like this

```
-e PG_DBNAME= "mapp"
```

Now

1. The web app work fine
2. If i log into shell via `docker exec ... bash` then env variables are also set

But if i log in via ipaddress and port number from ssh client then i am able to login but env variables are not set

Comment: have you added sshd to your docker container... i.e. are you ssh-ing into the container, or just the server that's running docker?

Comment: (note that generally adding ssh to the container is not recommended: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/)

Comment: @Anentropic . i think for develpoment phase it saves lot of headache. I will remove it when app is production ready

Comment: I don't see what ssh in the container buys you during development that `docker exec` doesn't provide

Comment: @Anentropic  i have saved ssh login details putty so that i can login inot separate conatiners with one click. othewise first  i need to login into machine and then do exec for separate containers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As commented in [issue 2569](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2569#issuecomment-27973910):

> This is expected. SSH wipes out the environment as part of the login process.
>
> One way to work around it is to dump the environment variables in `/etc/environment` (e.g. `env | grep _ >> /etc/environment`) before starting Supervisor.
> Further "login processes" should source this file, and tada! There is your environment.

That `env | grep _ >> /etc/environment` could be part of a default run script associated (through `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`) to your image.

---

[Daniel A.A. Pelsmaeker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146622/daniel-a-a-pelsmaeker) suggests [`jenkinsci/docker-ssh-agent` issue 33](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-ssh-agent/issues/33#issuecomment-597217350) for an approach that selects and sets all environment variables excluding a specific denylist:

> For my own uses I changed that line to the following:
>
> ```
> env | egrep -v "^(HOME=|USER=|MAIL=|LC_ALL=|LS_COLORS=|LANG=|HOSTNAME=|PWD=|TERM=|SHLVL=|LANGUAGE=|_=)" >> /etc/environment
> ```
>
> This takes all environment variables, except those listed, and appends then to /etc/environment, overriding any previously defined there.

Comment: my current starting point is superviord . if i make that line as entrypoint , how will then i start supervisord

Comment: @JohnKaff you can use a `CMD` with a `bash -c "env | grep _ >> /etc/environment && supervisord"`

Comment: Thanks currently i ahve this command  `cmd ["supervisord", "-n"]` in docker file , how can i chnage that

Comment: @JohnKaff `CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "env | grep _ >> /etc/environment && supervisord -n"]`

Comment: Why do you grep on an underscore?

Comment: @Apanatshka Because that was the approach suggested in https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2569#issuecomment-27973910: it captures all environment names with an _, which is often the case for application variables (like `PG_DBNAME`)

Comment: @VonC Ah, ok. That tripped me up because had a similar issue to this question but I also wanted to propagate the PATH variable, which was filtered here. Another danger of using this method is that e.g. your username contains an underscore, the HOME variable will be copied. I'd either copy specific variables or use `grep -v` to remove variables you definitely shouldn't copy.

Comment: @Apanatshka I fully agree. This "solution" has to be used sensibly.

Comment: Here is an approach that selects and sets all environment variables excluding a specific blacklist: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-ssh-agent/issues/33#issuecomment-597217350

Comment: @DanielA.A.Pelsmaeker Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the exact same problem. I found the example on [docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) appending variables by echo'ing to /etc/profile not the nicest way to do that. So here is my solution:

**Dockerbuild:**
I execute the docker build by the following command which also fetches the http_proxy, https_proxy and no_proxy variables from the
current shell session. The variables are passed as agruments with the --build-arg option.

```
[root@localhost dock-centOS]# docker build 
--build-arg http_proxy="{{ lookup('env', 'http_proxy')}}" 
--build-arg https_proxy="{{ lookup('env', 'https_proxy')}}" 
--build-arg no_proxy="{{ lookup('env', 'no_proxy')}}" 
-t my_pv_repo:centOS-with-sshd .
```

**Dockerfile:**
I use the following dockerfile snippet for setting the enviroment variables for all users. The ARG command is used instead of
ENV because i don't want docker to persist my variables in the image. The ARG variable is only available during the docker build.
The RUN command creates a bash script which is placed in the /etc/profile.d directory. During start-up of the container
/etc/profile script is run and sources all readable files in the /etc/profile.d directory.

```
FROM centos:7.3.1611

ARG http_proxy=$http_proxy
ARG https_proxy=$https_proxy
ARG no_proxy=$no_proxy
ARG JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45
ARG DOMAIN_HOME=/home/oracle/w001/D1/app/user_projects/domains/fancy_app_domain
ARG PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin
ARG XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority

RUN shebang='#!/usr/bin/env bash'; \
env_vars="export http_proxy=${http_proxy} https_proxy=${https_proxy} no_proxy=${no_proxy}"; \
env_vars+=' JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45 DOMAIN_HOME=/home/oracle/w001/D1/app/user_projects/domains/fancy_app_domain'; \
env_vars+=" PATH=${PATH}:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin XAUTHORITY=${XAUTHORITY}"; \
echo $shebang$'\n'$env_vars > /etc/profile.d/env_vars.sh
```

**Test result:** Well lets hit the cli to check if our environment variables are available during a ssh session.

```
[root@localhost vagrant]# docker exec -u root -it centOS-container bash
[root@33e7efab489c /]#
[root@33e7efab489c /]#
[root@33e7efab489c /]# cat /etc/profile.d/env_vars.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export http_proxy=http://10.0.2.2:3128 https_proxy=http://10.0.2.2:3128 no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1 JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45 DOMAIN_HOME=/home/oracle/w001/D1/app/user_projects/domains/fancy_app_domain PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
[root@33e7efab489c /]#
[root@33e7efab489c /]#
[root@33e7efab489c /]# printenv
HOSTNAME=33e7efab489c
TERM=xterm
http_proxy=http://10.0.2.2:3128
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin
DOMAIN_HOME=/home/oracle/w001/D1/app/user_projects/domains/fancy_app_domain
PWD=/
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
https_proxy=http://10.0.2.2:3128
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
XAUTHORITY=/root/.Xauthority
_=/usr/bin/printenv
[root@33e7efab489c /]#
[root@33e7efab489c /]#
[root@33e7efab489c /]# exit
[root@localhost vagrant]# exit
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ logout
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
me@my-mac$ ssh -X root@localhost -p 7022 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o IdentityFile=/development/workspace/supercalifragilisticexpialidocious-app/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
The authenticity of host '[localhost]:7022 ([127.0.0.1]:7022)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:dTd/vsmPTbrA3kPeIfArZMFEgfdlgjGHwMgE3Z5BgBc.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[localhost]:7022' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
/usr/bin/xauth:  file /root/.Xauthority does not exist
[root@33e7efab489c ~]# su - oracle
bash-4.2$
bash-4.2$
bash-4.2$ printenv
HOSTNAME=33e7efab489c
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
HISTSIZE=1000
http_proxy=http://10.0.2.2:3128
USER=oracle
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/oracle
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin
DOMAIN_HOME=/home/oracle/w001/D1/app/user_projects/domains/fancy_app_domain
PWD=/home/oracle
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
https_proxy=http://10.0.2.2:3128
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/oracle
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
LOGNAME=oracle
XAUTHORITY=/home/oracle/.Xauthority
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```